# Lazy ContentProvider load inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, lazy-loading, android-contentprovider

My database has 2 tables like table "A" and table "B". "B" has a foreign key column to "A". Now i load all my data of table "A" with a CursorLoader. To show more infos in my RecyclerView i want to load for each row the referencing data from table "B" but lazy. To make the inital load fast and load only data which i need.

The other way is to join table "A" and "B" and load this with a CursorLoader but then i need to split my data because i can have multiple similar rows of table "A" with multiple corresponding rows in table "B".

Has someone similar problem or any infos about this topic?

Comment: It is not a problem at all. And comparable with directly placing text and the laze load of images after that. That you will lazy load text instead of images does not matter.

Comment: But does it really slow down so much when you load it directly?

Comment: The performance increase was hugh by using lazy load. We talk about over 1000 items in table "A". But in fact i am more interested in the way how to load more data aync in a RecyclerView from a ContentProvider. Actual i block the ui by calling getContentResolver.query(). Its fast but not the best way. It musst be more like Glide or Picasso who track the position of the item and know if it is already out of range.

Comment: Use threads to handle all. And it is not too difficult to check if an item is still in view at the moment the text should be placed. But you would also place the text in an array for your adapter i suppose. And now you will regret having started to use Glide or Picasso for images as when you had not done so you could easily adapt your own code to serve text instead of an image ... ;-).

Comment: what adapter are you using?

Comment: I use a basic RecyclerView.Adapter which holds a list of Model from type "A". I convert inside my Loader the Cursor in Objects. Maybe i use a AsyncQueryHandler which loads all additional data and put them inside my models and finaly call dataSetChanged on the corresponding index?

Comment: try [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter, it uses the `Cursor` directly thus there is no need for any list of POJO

Comment: My problem is the lazy load of additional content not the POJO conversion. The adapter from @pskink can't provide this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The first way to have a nice lazy loading would be to first know how many of Bs you'd have for each A (I'm sure you could easily add that info in your first query).

That way, in your recycler view, the rows for lazy loaded data will already be there.

In a second time, I'd use an asynchronous loading mechanism (an Android Loader, or an Rx operation, whichever you prefer) to actually load the data when it needs to be displayed.